# How is Instant Articles updated on the Android App?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

It seems like Instant Articles are cached on Android's Facebook App. Does anyone know how this works in terms of getting articles updated?

We published an article, but then made some typo changes a few hours later. The changes came through on the iOS App, but not on the Android App.

Both apps had the first version of the article loaded. Does Android Facebook App cache it in another way, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that's a confirmed bug in the Android Facebook app, at least up to version 117. See the following link:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/731508133684525/